# Regex to remove hashtags but to keep first hashtag

Tags: regex, regexp-replace, hashtag

I want to remove all hashtags from a text but it should keep the first hashtag

Example text:

```
This is an example #DoNotRemoveThis #removethis #removethis #removethis
```

Expected result:

```
This is an example #DoNotRemoveThis
```

I'm using this

```
\#\w+\s?
```

but it remove all the hashtags. I want to keep the first hashtag

Comment: Depends on the flavour of regex; if PCRE is supported, you can use escape sequences and alternation to anchor your expression to the beginning of the string or the last match position and reset match starting points along the way. Something like this: `\A[^#]*#[^#]+\K#\w+|\G(?!\A)[^#]*\K#\w+`.

Comment: Or, more simply, capture everything up to and including the first hashtag and match every other hashtag via alternation, and replace them with the content of the captured group, which will be empty for every result but the first. E.g. search for `^([^#]*#\w+\b[^#]*)|#\w+` and replace by `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

This may require further knowledge as to what flavour of regex you are using. For example, if .NET (C#) you can do variable length look-behind, and thus the following pattern will do what you need:

```
(?<=#.*)(#\w+)/g
```

[Test at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DBhlHh/1)

However, this won't work in most other engines.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to match everything up to but not including the second hash symbol, right?

```
/^[^#]*#[^#]*/
```

That will match any number of non-hash characters, then a hash character, then more non-hash characters.